# login with LinkedIn does not login in linked in website through API

Tags: php, linkedin-api

when i login with LinkedIn API, i got code, access token and user details,but when i refresh main LinkedIn website it does not show logged in. i need to login in that site. actually it should show logged in because i have logged in through api. following is my code.

```
if ($config['Client_ID'] === '' || $config['Client_Secret'] === '') {
echo 'You need a API Key and Secret Key to test the sample code. Get one from <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/developer/apps/">https://www.linkedin.com/developer/apps/</a>';
exit;
} else {
echo '<a href="https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=' . $config['Client_ID'] . '&redirect_uri=' . $config['callback_url'] . '&state=98765EeFWf45A53sdfKef4233&scope=r_basicprofile r_emailaddress"><imgsrc="./images/linkedin_connect_button.png" alt="Sign in with LinkedIn"/></a>';
}
if (isset($_GET['code'])) { 

$url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken';
$param = 'grant_type=authorization_code&code=' . $_GET['code'] . '&redirect_uri=' . $config['callback_url'] . '&client_id=' . $config['Client_ID'] . '&client_secret=' . $config['Client_Secret'];
$return = (json_decode(post_curl($url, $param), true));

if (isset($return['error'])) { 
    $content = 'Some error occured<br><br>' . $return['error_description'] . '<br><br>Please Try again.';
} else { 
    $url = 'https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,firstName,lastName,pictureUrls::(original),headline,publicProfileUrl,location,industry,positions,email-address)?format=json&oauth2_access_token=' . $return['access_token'];
    $User = json_decode(post_curl($url)); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i have solved this problem by using following urls

https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization

https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken